# MySQL get latest 7 days reservations, grouped by NameResource

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tring to write a query, without a good resultset. 
I would to retreive a Number of reservations in last 7 days. 
Grouped by **NameOfResource**. 
When i'm tring to set a WHERE clause like this `prenotazioni.Data >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY` 
I get only NameOfResource with reservations in latest 7 days,
but not the rooms without reservations.

My Query was like that: (without WHERE the result is good)

```
SELECT count(*) as NReservationsFromWeek,Nomeroom FROM reservations
INNER JOIN room ON reservations.FKRoom = room.IDRoom
WHERE reservations.Data >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
group by room.IDRoom
```

Thank you to explain me where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`, if you want *all* rooms, even those with a count of `0`:

```
SELECT ro.IDRoom, ro.Nomeroom, COUNT(re.FKRoom) as NReservationsFromWeek,
FROM room ro LEFT JOIN
     reservations re 
     ON re.FKRoom = ro.IDRoom AND
        re.Data >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY ro.IDRoom, ro.Nomeroom;  -- Both unaggregated keys should be in the GROUP BY
```

Comment: Some syntax error, but solved. Concept are correct. 
LEFT JOIN is the solution.